# Como hacer que un switch genere un error para caputarlo

Tags: java, try-catch, switch

Este es un menú que tengo en mi Main, necesito que cuando se introduzca una opción que no es válida dé un error y pueda capturarlo con un try-catch (Usaría default que si que me funciona, pero no puedo usarlo como restricción del ejercicio).
El problema es que no entiendo porque al seleccionar un valor no válido (8, por ejemplo) entra en una especie de bucle y no hace nada.

```
    public static void menu(Protectora protectora, ClinicaVeterinaria clinica, Ayuntamiento ayuntamiento) {
        int eleccion;
        System.out.println("Este es el sistema de consultas de la protectora.\nEscoja una de las opciones siguientes:\n");
        System.out.println("1. Mostrar informacion sobre los animales de esta protectora.\n"+
                           "2. Solicitar adopcion o acogida de animal.\n"+
                           "3. Consultar listado de solicitudes de uno de nuestros animales.\n"+
                           "4. Calcular costes veterinarios previstos anuales.\n"+
                           "5. Calcular costes de una campaña de esterilizacion de gatas.\n"+
                           "6. Calcular estimacion de KGs de pienso de perro adulto para una semana.\n"+
                           "7. Calcular subvencion del ayuntamiento.\n"+
                           "0. Salir del programa.\n");
            
        eleccion = MENU.nextInt();
        switch (eleccion) {
            case 1: /* Mostrar informacion sobre los animales de esta protectora */
                listarInformacionAnimales(protectora);
                break;

            case 2: /* Solicitar adopcion o acogida de animal */
                crearSolicitudAnimal(protectora);
                break;

            case 3: /* Consultar listado de solicitudes de uno de nuestros animales */
                listarSolicitudesAnimal(protectora);
                break;

            case 4: /* Calcular costes veterinarios previstos anuales */
                listarGastosVeterinarios(protectora, clinica);
                break;

            case 5: /* Calcular costes de una campaña de esterilizacion de gatas */
                listarGastosEsterilizacion(protectora,clinica);
                break;

            case 6: /* Calcular estimacion de KGs de pienso de perro adulto para una semana */
                listarKgsPienso(protectora);
                break;

            case 7: /* Calcular subvencion del ayuntamiento */
                listarSubvencion(protectora, ayuntamiento);
                break;

            case 0: /* Salir del programa */
                System.out.println();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No se si sea correcto que esté dentro del switch yo lo pondría antes del switch.

```
    if(eleccion>7) {
        throw new  IllegalArgumentException("Ha elegido un número no válido");
    }
```

Y tu firma del metodo quedaría.

```
public static void menu(Protectora protectora, ClinicaVeterinaria clinica, Ayuntamiento ayuntamiento) throws  IllegalArgumentException{
```

Comment: Me sirve amigo, pero el otro problema que me surge es que tengo que lanzar el error pero no puedo parar la ejecución. He intentado añadir el menú y la captura de opción después del throw pero me da un warning de "unreachable".

Comment: Entonces me estas diciendo que tiene un while ? al llamar a menu? de ser asi pon el código, ahora bien si lo que necesitas es Lanzar el error  y no parar la ejecución, la descripción de tu problema esta mal planteada y en todo caso tambien necesito ver el metodo donde llamas a menu.